# TFS Reporting Cubes

Tags: tfs

Please find the screen shots below one of the screen shot is missing "Test Management Warehouse Sync" job in the list.How do i bring it back . The screen shots are from the Cube Status report in TFS

[image: Screen Shot with out Test management Job]

in the below image you can see the "Test Management Warehouse Sync" job

[image: Screen shot with Test Management Job]

Answer (score 0):

Which version of TFS are you using?

According to this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2010/07/12/monitoring-the-tfs-data-warehouse-faq.aspx), the reason why you get TF276000 error is:

Three jobs require exclusive access to the same warehouse resources:

- Optimize Databases (runs at 1:00 AM by default)
- Full Analysis Data Sync (runs at 2:00 AM by default)
- Incremental Analysis Data Sync (runs every two hours by default)

None of these jobs can run in parallel with any other job on the list. If one job is already in progress when another job starts, the second job will fail quickly with error TF276000.

Please try to follow the article below to manually process data warehouse and analysis services cube for Team Foundation Server. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff400237.aspx

If manually processing still received the same issue, you can try to delete the Tfs_Analysis database and recreate it using TFS Admin Console. To delete the Tfs_Analysis database, you can connect to **Analysis Service** using **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio**, expand the **Databases** node, and delete the Tfs_Analysis database.

Then rebuild warehouse and Analysis Services database by following the steps:

1. Launch TFS Admin Console>>Application Tier>>Reporting, in the right
   panel, click **Edit** to open the **Reporting** windows.
2. Under the **Analysis Services** tab, input the Tfs_Analysis under
   **Database** textbox, and re-provide the required account under **Account
   for accessing data source**.
3. Click **Ok** to generate the Tfs_Analysis database in **Analysis Services**.
4. Click **Start Jobs** and **Start Rebuild** to rebuild warehouse and the
   Analysis Services database.

After rebuilding the warehouse and the Analysis Services database, check whether the error disappear and whether you can see "Test Management Warehouse Sync" job.